# How to run a llvm pass in windows?

Tags: windows, llvm

Can someone tell me the steps to running the LLVMHello pass in windows?

Answer (score 2):

There is not dynamic linking on windows, so you need to link to pass into opt. Otherwise you might try to compile the whole LLVM into shared library, but this might be pretty nontrivial on windows.

Comment: Could you provide more details as to how to go about this procedure?

Comment: @Anton: Can you please explain how link passes to opt, is it using -load or something else, if using -load then what to link?

Comment: Is it still in this state in llvm 9?